# Set focus on a enabeled textbox

Tags: vba, excel

txtTimeLong textbox's Enable is False by default.

I have problem in code below as:
when case is "Minute", txtTimeLong textbox been enabled but focus jump on two TabIndex later.

How can I set focus on txtTimeLong text box, when case is "Minute"?

```
Select Case txtTimeUnit.Text
    Case "Minute"
        txtTimeLong.Enabled = True
        txtTimeLong.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
End Select
```

Comment: Where are you calling this code from?

Comment: And what is `case end`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I think that's intended to be `End Select` instead. @Mgae2M a more extensive code sample would be welcome indeed - we need to know how this code gets called.

Comment: Yes, I was correct that.

Comment: This code called in `txtTimeUnit_Exit` event.

Comment: Add UCASE() around the txtTimeUnit and compare it to MINUTE.  ????

Comment: Your code works just fine for me

Comment: letter cases are handled. This code jump on 2 tabindexes for me. I write a Msgbox in the begging of the container event procedure (`txtTimeUnit_Exit`), and seems this procedure run two times, when each exit of text box